# Hypothesis testing : t test for mean difference greater than a threshold

Tags: hypothesis-testing, equivalence

How do I test the hypotheses:

$H_0:  |p_0 - p_1| < c $     vs.     $H_1:  |p_0 - p_1| \ge c $

for some constant $c$.

Because sometimes we may want to adopt a new process only if it exceeds the current process by some threshold.

Comment: You may be able to get somewhere with equivalence tests and non-inferiority tests

Comment: I think you need to provide a specific example.  I think there are many examples in the literature where a composite null hypothesis is tested against a composite alternative.  Glen_b uses the word "may" because your objective is unclear.  In noninferiority and equivalence trials both null and alternative hypotheses are composite and specified constants like your c are used to mark an indifference region or a designated equivalence region For noninferiority there is a single constant involved while for equivalence there are two. You may want to check it out.

Comment: @netok any update on this question?